# Начали практику с 1959 года / в 1959 году

Tags: орфография, семантика

Корректна ли фраза: «начали свою практику с 1959 года»?

Разве можно начать (гл. соверш. вида) что-либо *с* некой даты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фраза не корректна. Начали когда? В 1959 году. Нужен предлог В.
Употребление предлога С — разговорный вариант. Иногда он звучит.

*С какого года они начали?* || Так не говорят.

*Они начали с сентября.* || Звучит так, что нужно оформить несколько месяцев в документе и решили сначала разобраться с сентябрём.

Глаголы совершенного вида не должны употребляться с предлогом С.
Похожие ошибочные примеры:
*Завод заработал с 1959 года.

Он закончил обучение с сентября.

Магазин открылся с февраля.*

При несовершенной форме есть продолжительность действия:
*Завод работал с 1959 года по 1970.*

Answer (score 0):

В НКРЯ — http://ruscorpora.ru/new/search-main.html — можно обнаружить достаточное число примеров, говорящее о корректности такого словосочетания:

> Первая в мире промышленная ГЭС появилась на Ниагарском водопаде.
>   Использовать его энергию люди начали с середины XVIII века. (Прошло
>   пять лет... // «Русский репортер», № 3 (181), 27 января 2011)
>
> Стараться мы начали с сентября. (Планирование беременности // Форум,
>   2005)
>
> В нашей стране планомерно заниматься этим начали с 50 ― 60-х годов
>   прошлого века. (Маргарита Спиричева. Ученье — вред // «Богатей»
>   (Саратов), 2003.04.10)
>
> Слаб, но шкодлив. Изменять ей начал с первого же года. (Фридрих
>   Горенштейн. Куча (1982) // «Октябрь», 1996)

Одно из свойств предлога ***с*** (род. п.) — обозначение интервала или множества, ***с*** указывает на их начальную точку [≈ 3][≠ 3] ◆ С восхода до заката. ◆ Начнём с понедельника. https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81

Среди устойчивых сочетаний бытуют: с каких пор; с утра; с младых лет; с самого начала.

Comment: Спасибо за примеры. Необх. уточнение. Вот, как вижу ситуацию:
Начать – гл. соверш. вида (действие в какой-л. момент) – перейти из одного состояния в другое, приступить к действиям. С – временной предлог (указывают на время), кот. исп-ся для указания начального момента для действий, вып-ся в теч. нек. времени. Вопрос: переход из одного состояния в другое – это не длящийся процесс, след-но данный переход может выполняться только _в_ нек. момент времени, а не _с_ нек. момента времени. След-но для гл. соверш. вида с указанием момента времени необх. скорее предлог «в». Что думаете?

Comment: Понимаю логику. Не хотите принять в качестве ключевого — слово «начать»? В нём нет намёка на предшествующее положение вещей. Дополню ответ.

Comment: По поводу «не с нек. момента времени»...  = Ядерная диссоциация протоядер и атомных ядер может начаться с момента резонансного воздействия на них извне.=